# I am trying to minus the user input number by 20 percent and count the times till the user number gets to 0 or less

Tags: python

```
import math
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))
times = 0 
amount = user
while amount != 0:
    interest = amount * 20 / 100
    amount = amount - interest
    times = times + 1
print(times)
```

I don't know why the output doesn't come neither an error. I am trying to minus the user input number by 20 percent and count the times till the user number gets to 0 or less.

I am expecting to print out

"your number is 6700 and with reduction of 20% in each interval it takes x times to make it 0."

Comment: Please repost your code, get rid of all the `----` and put it in a code block. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It will never become 0, it just gets really close to it.

Comment: Math note: removing 20% from something is the same as multiplying it by 0.8

Comment: Because you are using floating point math, your amount will NEVER reach zero.  You are essentially multiplying the number by 0.8 over and over and over.  That will result in a number that gets smaller and smaller and smaller, but never reaches zero.  Were you trying to subtract 20% of the ORIGINAL number?  That would be `interest = user * 20 / 100`.  Or did you mean to use integer arithmetic?  That would be `interest = amount * 20 // 100`.

Comment: For a simpler example, if you remove 90% starting from 1, you get 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, and so on. It just keeps getting more zeroes, but the `1` doesn't go away.

Comment: If the input is a positive number it will never become negative by repeatedly reducing it by any percentage

Comment: import math
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p = 0 
amount = user 
d = False
while amount != 0:
    interest = amount * 20 / 100
    amount = amount - interest
    p = p + 1
    
print(amount)    so i have to make less than 1 will it work.

Comment: @Barmar No, with 90% it does reach zero. Try it.

Comment: i wanted to ask user a number like 100. and this 100 is first be processed to take its 20 percent. then the result from 20 percent is then subtracted to user number. so times will then become 1. so, if we print the user number will be 80 but instead of printing 80 we again take 80 and do the same process and make times increase by each interval process. this 80 will processed for 20 percent and the result will be 16. and 80-16 = 64 and times will change to 2. and so on until it reaches negative result so we can tell it is less than zero so we stop the while loop and print the number of times

Comment: IT WILL NEVER REACH ZERO.  That's the point.  You will keep subtracting smaller and smaller numbers each time.  Think about a stick.  Break the stick in half.  Now break it in half again.  And again.  The stick gets very, very small, but it never disappears.  Have you not added `print(interest,amount)` in your loop so you can watch the process?

Comment: @KellyBundy -- Well, it doesn't literally reach zero -- we get an undiagnosed floating point underflow.

Comment: Thank you to all participants. it works now. if i use 1 it works. thank you.

Comment: The reason it works in the real world is because you can't charge fractional cents, so it gets rounded up.

Comment: @TimRoberts It does literally reach zero and the loop stops. And in the last step, both `amount` and `interest` are `5e-324`, so the subtraction yields *exactly* zero, that's no underflow. But some previous steps apparently are underflows, at least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow?wprov=sfla1) says underflow is regarding the normals, and subnormals provide "gradual underflow".

Answer (score -1):

I think the error in your code is that the interest is calculated inside the while so for example:

If you introduce 100 the 20% is 20 and you get 80, but beacuse the interest is inside the while loop your code now will calculate de 20% of 80 giving you 16 as the interest

Also the While Loope should be >0 beacuse if not it would enter to an infinite loop after passing 0

So this would be my approach. basically in all the existing numbers would give me 5 the output,

```
import math


user = int(input("Enter a number:"))
times = 0 
amount = user
interest = amount * .20
while amount > 0:
    amount = amount - interest 
    times += 1
print(times)
```

Comment: Your algorithm does reach zero, but that's not what the original poster wanted.  He wants "compound interest", like a mortgage loan.

Comment: Aaaaaa, ok, Later I will try to solve it

Comment: Tecnicaly then is imposible beacuse the interest would never be Zeo percent, unless ther is  condition that when the interest gets to a certain interval it automatically turns to zero

Comment: Yes, that's EXACTLY the problem.  And it's not that interest never gets to "zero percent", it's that it doesn't get to "zero dollars".  No matter how small you get, 20% of it is still bigger than zero (until you underflow the floats).